# Collecting coefficient list of arbitrary polynomial

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion, coefficients

Say I have a polynomial like:
`1+x^(n)+3x^(n+1)+3nx^(3n+4)`

I want to extract the coefficient list `{1,1,3,3n}`.

I've been toying around with SeriesCoefficient and CoefficientList but they don't seem to work because the exponent $n$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the sum of terms to a list of terms (using `Apply`), then replace all expressions like `Power[x,_]` with `1`. This approach should return the list of coefficients of the polynomial despite arbitrary constants throughout.

```
eqn = 1 + x^(n) + 3 x^(n + 1) + 3 n x^(3 n + 4)
List @@ eqn /. Power[x, _] -> 1
```

Result:

```
{1, 1, 3, 3 n}
```